# Select works, but can't update rows with a string of all spaces -- why?

Tags: mysql

This query

```
SELECT count(data_id)
FROM cdiac_data_AL
WHERE (data_id >= 1 and data_id <= 30437) 
AND (TMIN_flags = '')
```

returns 844 records, but update query affects 0 records:

```
UPDATE cdiac_data_AL set TMIN_flags='   ' 
WHERE (data_id >= 1 and data_id <= 30437)  
AND ( TMIN_flags = '' )
```

What am I missing?

TMIN_flags is:

```
char(3) ascii_general_ci, allow null, default NULL
```

Comment: addendum. I had previously detected TMIN_flags is null and set TMIN_flags='   ' and those were all set to ''.  is there something funny with char?  I usually use varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the CHAR data type does not save trailing spaces.
You should change TMIN_flags data type to `binary`

Comment: blurg, this is frustrating, but thanks.  complicates my WHERE clauses when searching for a certain char by index.  will look into substring routines to see how they handle out of bounds indexes.